# Absolute positioned child should be at the same size as its parent as im resizing the screen between 320px and 767px screen width

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div `header-mobile-banner`, and a child div `header-mobile-graydiv` which is positioned absolute.  I want both divs to be at the same size as im resizing the screen between 320px and 767px screen width (responsive). Both div should be responsive. The child div which is absolute should follow the size of its parent.

```css
@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:767px) { 
  #myCarousel {display: none;}
  .carousel {display: none;}
  .header-mobile-banner {width: 100%; height: 663.31px; padding: 0; top: 0; background-image: url("../img/head_banner.jpg"); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: contain;}
  .header-mobile-graydiv {background-color: black; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; horizontal-align: middle; bottom: 0;}
  .header-mobile-graydiv h3 {font-size: 50px;}
  .header-mobile-graydiv h1 {font-size: 92px;}
  .header-mobile-graydiv h4 {font-size: 39px;}
  .header-mobile-graydiv p {font-size: 20px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="header-mobile-banner">
  <div class="header-mobile-graydiv">
    <h3 class="font-GaramondPremierePro white">WELCOME TO</h3>
    <h1 class="font-GreatVibes white">hello world</h1>
    <h4 class="font-GaramondPremierePro white">hello world</h4>
    <p class="font-CormorantGaramond white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod <br> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna. aliqua. Ut enim ad minim</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ...and what doesn't work? There's no question in your question.

Comment: wait ill edit it :)

Answer (score 0):

I take it the question is implied in the title. Your parent DIV should be positioned for the child DIV absolute positioning to work correctly. Try setting `position: relative;` on the parent. The child DIV should have `overflow` set, try `auto` or `scroll`. Note also that 0 values don't require units. Official documentation on [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#css) is worth reading.

Comment: thanks but i solved my prob by putting a class on the image directly :)

Answer (score 0):

@benok whatever you have right now in your code-base, just remove bottom:0 from your css and you will see your desired results. Although this is not the right way to achieve this.

Comment: thanks but i solved my prob by putting a class on the image directly :)